# Laravel URL is not working only / or index.php is working

Tags: .htaccess

Laravel URL is not working only / or index.php is working.
if I hit URL like /login it not work give me internal server error,
e.g : https://realtorbyrank.com/ this is my domain it is only working by it url and by /index.php if i hit any other url like https://realtorbyrank.com/leaderboard or https://realtorbyrank.com/allrealtor it produce page not found or 404 error,

the problem is only with .htaccess file.
also i have check that this problem is only with in hosting site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file add this content,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
     # Handle Front Controller...
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

also create a index.php file on root directory, and add this content,

```
<?php
    $uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
    );
    if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
    }
    require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```